# Calculate a lag or lead mean in r

Tags: r, time-series

I need to calculate a lag or lead mean between two sequential values in a table and then output the means to a new column. I can write a for loop for this operation, but would prefer to avoid this so that the codes is more flexible. Is it possible to do this operation in dplyr and tidyr? Below is an example data set and the desired result. Thanks in advance.

```
DATA = data.frame(POO = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10 , 20))

RESULTS  = data.frame(POO = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10 , 20), YEY = c(0,3,5,7,9,15))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df1<-structure(list(POO = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 20)), .Names = "POO", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")   
library(dplyr)
libary(zoo) # for rollmean function
df1 %>%  # df1 is your data frame
mutate(TEY=rollmean(POO,2,fill=0,align="right"))
  POO TEY
1   2   0
2   4   3
3   6   5
4   8   7
5  10   9
6  20  15
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `filter`:

```
DATA$YEY <- filter(DATA$POO, c(1, 1)/2, sides = 1)
#  POO YEY
#1   2  NA
#2   4   3
#3   6   5
#4   8   7
#5  10   9
#6  20  15
```

You can then substitute `NA` with `0`, but I don't understand the logic behind that.

Note that `filter` gets masked by package dplyr unfortunately. You might need to use `stats::filter`, if you have attached dplyr.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a way in `dplyr`:

```
DATA %>%
    mutate(YEY = (POO + lag(POO)) / 2)
```

This also has NA in the first row, which you could fix afterwards if you need to.